# Grouping columns by type in kdb+

Tags: kdb

I have a requirement, where I need to find the count of columns having different type e.g.
Table: col: x,y,z,c
It should return col: 2, because x and y are of same type say float64.

Comment: Please provide reproducible examples with actual  q/kdb code

Comment: Something like,
Select from tb1 where date within [a,b] group by type

Comment: That's not a reproducible example! You need to create/supply a code sample of what your table looks like, and how you expect the output to look like

Answer (score 1):

If you could provide more comprehensive examples of expected outputs or what you have tried thus far that would be appreciated. From what I can gather you are looking to count how many columns have a particular datatype. In which case the following example should help.
Here I have a sample table with 3 different datatypes, one of which is used on two columns.

```
q)n:100;table:([] a:n?.z.T; b:n?(`a`b`c); c:til n; d:n?(`a`b`c))
```

We can use meta to establish the data types of each column where t is the type.

```
 q)meta table
c| t f a
-| -----
a| t
b| s
c| j
d| s
```

Now we can group datatypes

```
q)count each group exec t from meta table
t| 1
s| 2
j| 1
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: This seems pretty close, but I m getting length error.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please Aarif

Comment: This works for me, except I need to put where condition like date within [a,b]

Comment: The reason being as we are accessing meta information, we don't have date column available. Any suggestions how to embed date condition in above query

Comment: Refer to my answer Aarif, you can most easily do that by temporarily using .Q.view

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work, given the limited information provided

```
q)tab:([]col1:10?`3;col2:10?.Q.a;col3:10?10.0;col4:10?10.0;col5:10#enlist 10?10.0)
q)select cnt:count i ,column:c by typ:t from meta tab
typ| column     cnt
---| --------------
F  | ,`col5     1  
c  | ,`col2     1  
f  | `col3`col4 2  
s  | ,`col1     1
```

If you want to apply a date restriction for a HDB then you can do so most easily with .Q.view

```
// First restrict the view, which will adjust the meta you receive 
.Q.view 2#date;
// Then get the results you want
q)select cnt:count i ,column:c by typ:t from meta tab
```

Comment: What if column 3 has both string and float values?

Comment: Then it's null type, mixed. And will show up as such

Comment: Burrowing down for each mixed type to resolve all the individual types will be very expensive, You will need to check each row. Is this important enough to have a very long computation time?

Comment: Yeah.. I have mixed type data in few columns.. thanks

Comment: That's not really answering my question. I know you have mixed type, I'm asking if it's critical enough to literally read through all the mixed type columns. Unless you are sure enough that the mixed type columns are **always** the same (i.e., colA is always a (string;float)). Which I suspect is not the case as you want to apply a where clause for given dates

Comment: Yeah... It's my critical requirement to return count of types by iterating through each row. Initially I thought by grouping first and then iterating will reduce some computation.

Comment: My advice would be to build a query to hit each date partition and determine all the types, handling mixed type columns.